# How to call method of my ViewController from separate non UIViewController Class

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

What Im trying is NetworkCall(Asyncronous call) in a seprate class file. 
When network call Get Completed it should throw a function callBack in my actuall ViewController and Update some UI-Views

I have a FacilitiesNewVC.Swift Class Like this

```
class FacilitiesNewVC: UIViewController, RoomsDataProtocol {
    var data = NSMutableData()
    var roomsData = RoomsData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //Image Background

        roomsData.startConnection();
    }

    // Overriden Method (Not Called)
    func didFinishLoadingUrl(jsonResult:NSDictionary) -> Void{
        //This Method not getting called
        println("In View Controller")
    }
}
```

Note: **roomsData.startConnection();**

here is the RoomsData.Swift

```
class RoomsData: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate  {
    var data = NSMutableData()
    var callBack:RoomsDataProtocol?

    func startConnection(){
        let urlPath: String = "http://blue.genetechz.com/qadir/bed_room.php"
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!

        println("startConnection");
        connection.start()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
         self.data.appendData(data)
         println("connection");
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        println("connectionDidFinishLoading");

        var err: NSError
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        callBack?.didFinishLoadingUrl(jsonResult); // Call the Overriden Method in FacilitiesNewVC

        println("RoomsData")
    }
}
```

and Lastly here is my protocol i.e RoomsDataProtocol

```
protocol RoomsDataProtocol {
    func didFinishLoadingUrl(jsonData:NSDictionary)
}
```

Why is my overriden method in the FacilitiesNewVC.swift Class (i.e didFinishLoadingUrl() ) is not getting called?

Comment: I don't see where you set the `callback` property. It is probably `nil` when you call `didFinishLoadingUrl`.

Comment: @user623396 Yes Its nil. Im new to Swift. How should I Initialize my callBack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, there is no line that actually sets the `callBack` variable in your `RoomsData` class. Thus the `?.` operator does not call your method in the line

```
callBack?.didFinishLoadingUrl(jsonResult);
```

I would suggest that you add

```
roomsData.callBack = self
```

somewhere before calling

```
roomsData.startConnection();
```

in your `FacilitiesNewVC` class.